# Text rendering issue

Tags: firefox, windows-7, text-rendering, webpage-rendering

In some site, i've issues of text rendering with firefox and other firefox based browser like Palemoon

This in an example of the rendering issue i've
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTKI2.png

In google Chrome the same text is ok. Have you an idea of what is cause this strange issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try unchecking "Use hardware acceleration when possible" in Advanced options. This has helped me with the same problem.